# BeautifulSoup parser adds unnecessary closing html tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

For example

you have html like

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

**python:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3

URL = 'html file'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

page = http.request('GET', URL)
soup = bs(page.data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

And if you parse it using BeautifulSoup in python and print it with prettify it will give output like this

**output:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
            <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                </meta>
             </meta>
         </meta>
     </meta>
  </meta>
</head>
```

but if you have html meta tag like

```
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials" />
```

It will give output as it is. It won't add an ending tag

so how to stop BeautifulSoup from adding unnecessary ending tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you just need to change your `html` parser to `lxml` parser

**then you python script will be**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3

URL = 'html file'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

page = http.request('GET', URL)
soup = bs(page.data, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

you just need to change `soup = bs(page.data, 'html.parser')` to `soup = bs(page.data, 'lxml')`