# BeautifulSoup closes automatically html tags that are unclosed

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an issue with BeautifukSoup. Whenever I parse an HTML input, it closes HTML tags that weren't closed (e.g. `<input>` , or tags that weren't closed by mistake).

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tags = BeautifulSoup('<span id="100" class="test">', "html.parser")
print(str(tags))
```

Prints:

```
<span id="100" class="test"></span>
```

My main goal here is to preserve the original shape of the HTML input after parsing it.

I found that it's possible by using ["XML" parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704600/beautifulsoup-parser-adds-unnecessary-closing-html-tags) instead of "html.parser", but I am looking to solve this for "html.parser".

Comment: It's parsing the HTML into a DOM structure, it doesn't preserve the actual HTML text. When you print it, it prints it in the standard way.

Comment: Just like when you load invalid HTML into a browser, and then view the Elements tab of DevTools. It shows it in a canonical format, not the original HTML.

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as your previous question about order of attributes.

Comment: I see! I thought of this but I cannot solve it. is it possible to do so?

Comment: If you want to process the HTML as text, don't parse it first. Write your own code that processes the raw text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [poke through `bs4` internals](https://git.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/tree/bs4/builder/__init__.py?h=4.12.2#n389) and modify how the `html.parser` treats HTML (this works for my version `bs4==4.12.2`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder import builder_registry
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter


class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            void_element_close_prefix=""
        )  # <-- use void_element_close_prefix="" here

    def attributes(self, tag):
        yield from tag.attrs.items()


html_text = """\
<closed_tag>
    <my_tag id="xxx">
    <my_other_tag id="zzz">
</closed_tag>"""

builder_registry.lookup("html.parser").empty_element_tags = {"my_tag", "my_other_tag"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
print(soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode())
```

Prints:

```html
<closed_tag>
<my_tag id="xxx">
<my_other_tag id="zzz">
</closed_tag>
```

Comment: While I was testing it on longer htmls, it seems that it skips closed tags. So if I have `<tr><td><p> DE </p></td></tr>` it will output `<tr><td><p> DE `, because I added [tr, td, p] tags to `builder_registry.lookup("html.parser").empty_element_tags`. Is this what it meant to do?

Comment: @Minions You shouldn't add `<tr>`/`<td>`/`<p>` to `empty_element_tags`, because they have always some content. `empty_element_tags` should be used only for tags without content.

Comment: aaah I see. So this won't solve cases where span contains content but weren't closed, right?

Comment: Yes. That seems like malformed HTML. You can try use `html5lib` parser, but this parser will treat the document like browsers do (it will close the tag where it should by the HTML5 specification).